# Adding event handler using javascript doesnt work in IE

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add an event handler on a page through javascript. What I tried is as follows,

```
var span=document.getElementById("WD67");  
span.setAttribute("onchange","alert('hello');");
```

But though the event handler attribute gets added, it doesn't fire when the page is viewed in IE, however in Firefox it works properly. How do I get IE to recognize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use attributes for that. The best way to add event handlers is using `addEventListener` (all modern browsers) or `attachEvent` (IE<9). Furthermore, use a handler function reference (wrap `alert('hello')` in a function).

A crossbrowser function to add handlers to elements:

```
function addHandler(obj,htype,fn){
    if (obj.addEventListener){
     obj.addEventListener(htype, fn);
    } else {
     obj.attachEvent('on'+htype,fn);
    }
}
// usage
var mySpan=document.getElementById("WD67");
addHandler(mySpan,'change',function(){alert('hello')});
```

See also: [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/fsMya/)

Comment: Hi this actually throws an error, - not enough arguments. Same thing happens when trying out on the site you have mentioned too. I'm not able to identify. Could you please check?

Comment: You're running firefox, I suppose? `obj.addEventListener(htype, fn, true);` should do the trick there. See also: http://jsfiddle.net/PRAd3/

Comment: I did try that, but In both, Firefox and IE the error is thrown.

Comment: Maybe a cache problem? In my IE (8,9) and Firefox (5.0) I don't see problems

Comment: You are right mate. There was an issue in the test page I was using that prevented the functions. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
var span = document.getElementById("WD67");
span.onchange = function(){ alert('hello'); };
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/2MM9H/  Does that work for you? Which version of IE are you using?

Comment: Yes it is.. It was the bug in my test page that was hindering yesterday. Thanks.